# How can I run multiple selected notebook cells in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

How to run multiple selected code chunks of Jupyter notebook in VS Code IDE?
After selecting some consecutive code cells with Shift+Down Arrow, how do I run the cells?
This is easily done in Jupyter notebook IDE but I can not figure it out in VS Code IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this didn't always work, but I can run consecutive selected shells using Shift+Enter, same as running a single selected cell.

Comment: This seems to work unless the group of cells has nesting due to Markdown.